# Form remote=> true returns html instead of js when using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, carrierwave

I'm a newbie to rails and I faced some difficulties when I tried to upload file using carrierwave through Ajax. Below are the coding:

```
composition.rb

class Composition < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :question_paper
 mount_uploader :image_path, ImageUploader

 validates :question_title, presence: true
 validates :topic, presence: true
 validates :image_path, presence: true  
end

question_paper_generations_controller.rb

def composition
 @composition = Composition.new

 respond_to do |format|
   format.js
 end
end

def composition_create
  @teacher = current_teacher
  @question_paper = @teacher.question_papers

  comp_prms = composition_params

  if comp_prms[:guided] == "Guided"
    comp_prms[:guided] = true
  else
    comp_prms[:guided] = false
  end

  comp_prms[:lvl_of_difficulty] = params[:composition][:lvl_of_difficulty][0].to_i

  @composition = @question_paper.last.compositions.new(comp_prms)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @composition.save
      if params[:composition][:guided] == "Guided"
        format.js { render :action => "comp_guided" }
      elsif params[:composition][:guided] == "Not Guided"
        format.js { render :action => "comp_not_guided" }
      end
    else
      render 'composition'
    end
  end
end

composition.html.erb

<%= form_for(@composition, url: composition_path, remote: true) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/composition_error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :question_title %>
  <%= f.text_field :question_title, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :guided %>
  <%= f.select :guided, options_for_select([['Guided'], ['Not Guided']]), {}, { class: 'form-control'} %>

  <%= f.label :topic %>
  <%= f.text_field :topic, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :level_of_difficulty %>
  <%= f.select :lvl_of_difficulty, options_for_select([['1 - Easy'], ['2 - Moderate'], ['3 - Hard']]), {}, { class: 'form-control'} %>

  <%= f.label :composition_image %>
  <%= f.file_field :image_path, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save and Continue", class: "btn btn-primary", :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

First of all, I get a 406 error when I tried to submit the form. I fix by adding a hidden_tag `<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>` in the form to include the authenticity token. The form submitted successfully but it was sent as HTML not JS and this is not what I want because I need to submit it through Ajax and execute some javascript after form submission.

Before adding `<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>`

```
rails server log

Started POST "/composition" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-12 09:34:38 +0800
Processing by QuestionPaperGenerationsController#composition_create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "composition"=>{"question_title"=>"你好", 
"guided"=>"Guided", "topic"=>"你好", "lvl_of_difficulty"=>"1 - Easy", 
"image_path"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xc509850 @tempfile=#
<Tempfile:C:/Users/weiki/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20180312-4592-
19d63mw.jpg>, @original_filename="bg.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"composition[image_path]\"; 
filename=\"bg.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save and 
Continue"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken 
(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):

actionpack (5.1.2) 
lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:195:in 
`handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (5.1.2) 
lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:227:in 
`handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (5.1.2) 
lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:222:in 
`verify_authenticity_token'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in 
make_lambda'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:197:in `block (2 
levels) in halting'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 
levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block in 
halting'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in 
invoke_before'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in 
`process_action'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in 
`process_action'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in 
`block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in 
instrument'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in 
`instrument'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in 
`instrument'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in 
`process_action'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in 
`process_action'
 activerecord (5.1.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in 
`process_action'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:46:in `block in 
serve'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:832:in `call'
remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block 
in call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in 
`call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in 
`call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in 
tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.2) 
lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

After adding `<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>`

```
rails server log

Started POST "/composition" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-12 09:42:30 +0800
Processing by QuestionPaperGenerationsController#composition_create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"u+xjkaGZ3KQ4WRxYfbhsV7+tPsuhtaKDmLvo1ToLG5+DUgHbeWqtsgsy9ogJRQGinXTAYQQ2ge1CKViyJFPtAg==", "composition"=>{"question_title"=>"你好", "guided"=>"Guided", "topic"=>"你好", "lvl_of_difficulty"=>"1 - Easy", "image_path"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xdf30b18 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/weiki/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20180312-4592-fio4v3.jpg>, @original_filename="72030c760581fc40475a604dbb55bbb7.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"composition[image_path]\"; filename=\"72030c760581fc40475a604dbb55bbb7.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save and Continue"}
Teacher Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
QuestionPaper Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "question_papers".* FROM "question_papers" INNER JOIN "question_papers_teachers" ON "question_papers"."id" = "question_papers_teachers"."question_paper_id" WHERE "question_papers_teachers"."teacher_id" = ? ORDER BY "question_papers"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["teacher_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 (0.0ms)  begin transaction
 SQL (3.0ms)  INSERT INTO "compositions" ("question_title", "image_path", "guided", "lvl_of_difficulty", "topic", "question_paper_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["question_title", "你好"], ["image_path", "72030c760581fc40475a604dbb55bbb7.jpg"], ["guided", "t"], ["lvl_of_difficulty", 1], ["topic", "你好"], ["question_paper_id", 1], ["created_at", "2018-03-12 01:42:30.578211"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-12 01:42:30.578211"]]
 (142.8ms)  commit transaction
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 268ms (ActiveRecord: 147.8ms)

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/question_paper_generations_controller.rb:64:in `composition_create'
```

After rounds of debugging, I found out it responded in HTML not JS which I do not want. Then, I found out a gem - remotipart which I don't have to add the hidden_tag and the form can submit through Ajax but it do not works for Rails 5.1. So, any idea on how can I do it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really hard to debug a verbal description of your code :) Can you please edit your question and add all the relevant code snippets (even though they're not working) for us to have a look at? Also add the error you got in the console/log-file and anything else that can help us to help you. If you tried different approaches to solve it, add all the approaches. :) Note: please don't add code in comments (here where I'm writing now) because code-formatting here is awful and hard to read), definitely edit your question and add it there :)

Comment: @TarynEast Hey, thanks for replying. I have updated the code snippet that is related.

Comment: Hmmm... I just googled and: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/412

Comment: So, the only way is to use other library other than carrierwave? Because remotipart gem is not working for rails 5.1.

Comment: I just realized it's not carrierwave's problem but rails do not allow file upload through ajax. I found some workarounds such as iframe trick. But is there any simpler workaround for this?

Comment: Looking at that other thread - it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 1):

After rounds of researching, I found out I configured remotipart wrongly and I managed to perfom form submission with file_field through Ajax.